# Exoplayer bandwith speed

Tags: android, exoplayer

is there any way to get download speed of stream playback with exoplayer on android?
I have tried to investigate it, but the information I have found is outdated

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this file for more information:
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter