# Check the download rate of video streaming in exo player

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to get the amount of download a video when streaming it in exo-player

Is there a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61167728/exoplayer-bandwith-speed